# Unusual problem involving Unicode

Tags: equations, debugging

I have tried compiling the following in ShareLaTeX, but I've been having issues involving Unicode, which I'm sure is not in this line.

```
\begin{equation}
    f(Q, \omega) = A_0(Q)\delta(⁢\omega)\sum_{l}^{N-1}A_l(Q)
    \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\tau_l}{1+\omega^2\tau^2}
    \label{eq1}
\end{equation}
```

When I compile I get the error:

```
" Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ⁢ (U+2062)

(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 f(Q, \omega) = A_0(Q)\delta(⁢
                                    \omega)\sum_{l}^{N-1}A_l(Q)\frac{1}{\pi}...

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it."
```

Answer (score 3):

The line is broken in your error message at the point where LaTeX has run into problems:

```
l.10 f(Q, \omega) = A_0(Q)\delta(⁢
                                    \omega)\sum_{l}^{N-1}A_l(Q)\frac{1}{\pi}...
```

The character that it is struggling with is U+2062 which is the "invisible times" character, so you can see why you're having problems spotting it, but I promise you it is there. If you move your cursor to the `\` of `\omega` and hit backspace it should get rid of the character. I don't know how you've ended up with it in your source code, but if you've copied something in from somewhere that might be the problem. With the character removed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  f(Q, \omega) = A_0(Q)\delta(\omega)\sum_{l}^{N-1}A_l(Q)
  \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\tau_l}{1+\omega^2\tau^2}
  \label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Compiles fine.

[image]